# Jitsi Docker server JWT authentication does not work. Why?

Tags: docker, authentication, jwt, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am trying to enable jwt authentication for my self-hosted (Docker) Jitsi server. There is a guide on self hosting with Docker and on that guide, it tells how to enable authentication. This is the guide: https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker

Now I will copy and paste the autentication part from that guide so that you can see it more clearly.

> Authentication can be controlled with the environment
> variables below. If guest access is enabled, unauthenticated users
> will need to wait until a user authenticates before they can join a
> room. If guest access is not enabled, every user will need to
> authenticate before they can join.
> [image]
>
> Authentication using JWT tokens You can use JWT tokens to authenticate
> users. To enable it you have to enable authentication with ENABLE_AUTH
> and set AUTH_TYPE to jwt...

After these instructions, I changed my .env file. I did the configurations told above. Then I did `docker-compose down`. Then I removed the `~/.jitsi-meet-cfg` and then created again with mkdir. Then I ran the command `docker-compose up -d`.

Then to try it, I am entering the URL:

```
https://{ip_add}:8443/room?jwt=randomwords
```

I am connecting to the server remotely thus I am accessing it with an ip. And because I did not provide a token, I should not be able to create/join to a meeting but I am able to. Whatever I write to the url I still can join.

Can someone help?

Comment: when you specify the AUTH_TYPE=jwt you must to fill also APP_ID and APP_SECRET
here you can find the reference: https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker#authentication-using-jwt-tokens
for generating a valid token: https://jwt.io